# EF Core Not Sending All Modified Fields for Update

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm doing a simple update (using EF Core 3.1.2 with SQL backend) and have not been able to learn why one field is failing to get sent to the db.

I have an update call, where I can see the value for DateModified that I'm wanting to be sent:
[image]

However, using SQL Profiler, I can see that this is what is actually being sent AND the DateModified field is NOT being sent to SQL at all:

[image]

Here is the object trying to be sent:

```
public class AVO : BasePropertiesWithID
{
    //[Authorize(Policy = "AllEmployees")]
    [ForeignKey("DivisionID")]
    public int DivisionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the base class that contains the DateModified field (not being sent) and the DateInserted field that IS being sent:

```
    public class BasePropertiesWithID
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 9990)]
    [DefaultValue("autoProcess")]
    public string InsertedBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 9991)]
    public DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 9992)]
    [DefaultValue("autoProcess")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 9993)]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

}
```

I've been using this base class for a long time with no trouble and no version of EF have I ever experienced this. I have been unsuccessful with searches for info and while I did find this [Why is EF Core Update failing to update a modified column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378157/why-is-ef-core-update-failing-to-update-a-modified-column) it wasn't helpful for me.

Why is a field failing to even be sent? Can anyone offer WHY or how to resolve this?? THANKS!

EDIT: How this entity is added to EF
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: just for clarity i believe you using ef-6 and not core... you should state so...

Comment: @Seabizkit I am using EF Core 3.1.2 for clarification

Comment: sorry i assumed as none related but `[Column(Order = 9992)]` doesnt work in core https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11314. back to your problem most interesting looks 100% correct my guess is remove the line in configure... which is for DataModfied with ,valueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdated... and see what happens

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the info. Looks like a recent issue being looked into. 12 days ago there was a workaround added. I'll dig in some more and respond with what I end up implementing. Thank you @Seabizkit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is a field failing to even be sent?

Because you configured the property to have it's value generated on add or update:

[image]

Which instructs EF to reload that value from the database after each update. To apply client-side updates you have to set the `SetAfterSaveBehavior` to `PropertySaveBehavior.Save` in the model like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(b => b.ModifiedAt).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Save);
```

eg

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EfCore3Test
{

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(p => p.ModifiedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(b => b.ModifiedAt).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Save);

        }
        private static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddFilter((category, level) =>
               category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
               && level == LogLevel.Information).AddConsole();
        });


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                          .UseSqlServer("Server=.;database=EfCore3Test;Integrated Security=true",
                                        o => o.UseRelationalNulls());

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }





    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using var db = new Db();

            db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var p = new Person() { Name = "Fred" };
            db.Set<Person>().Add(p);
            db.SaveChanges();

            p.Name = "Fred2";
            p.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
            db.Set<Person>().Update(p);
            db.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
  }
}
```

outputs

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p1='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [Person] SET [ModifiedAt] = @p0, [Name] = @p1
      WHERE [Id] = @p2;
      SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much David Browne. Initially, @Seabizkit got me looking in the right direction and finding many issues/perspectives. What I eventually did was simply change the base entity property to ValueGeneratedOnAdd only since I'm sending the value and it works as expected; but the most valuable aspect of all of this was learning more about how it actually worked, finding out why the ValueGenerator was coming through as null, and being able to create the ValueGenerator to do what I actually want it to do. I definitely say it is a doc issue that could be clarified. Thank you both very much!